# How to render a content in index template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a noindex method and I want to render content for this method in index template, because noindex.html.erb has the same content as index.html.erb.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails' [render method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

In your `noindex` action:

```
render 'index'
```